# VS402925: BuildId is not valid. Make sure that the build id is valid and try again

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to deploy my application onto an on prem server in VSTS and I am getting this error message;

```
VS402925: BuildId '20170615.2' is not valid. Make sure that the build id is valid and try again.
```

I specify the Build Id when I create the deploy process.
The BuildId does exist so why would it not be valid?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the build ID. That's the build *number*. The build ID is a sequential number that's assigned by the system.

Per the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-a-list-of-builds), you can get a build id for a given build as follows:

`GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/build/builds?buildNumber=<your build number>&api-version=2.0`

You may also need to specify the `definitionId` property to filter the list further.

Comment: I could not duplicate the URL in your answer. I did find a list of builds from looking at the Agent queues (Agents for pool hosted VS2017). However when I use the ID field for the latest build as the buildId, I get an error message indicating that this is not the correct6 buildId; "Build with Id: 101 is not valid. Make sure that the build is succeeded or partially succeeded and it is not deleted."

Comment: I had a look in the build logs and I found a number I could work out is the buildId although it is not specified as such. I run the deploy job and it is correct (although I have a new bug to fix). Anyway your answer so far has clarified the difference between build number and build id and that has helped me move forward. I would if possible like an easier way of finding it.

Answer (score 2):

The Id in the build list of agent pool is not the build id.

The easy way to get the build ID from the URL:

1. Just open a build in web browser
2. The URL format likes:

   https://[account].visualstudio.com/[Team Project]/_build/index?buildId=[**build id**]

Comment: Thank you, that is the final missing piece.